# Audience Manager Get Contact Fails

Tags: web8, audience-manager

There is a console application which goes through all contacts in Audience DB and writes to log some information for later analysis.

The code is working fine on one CM server but on another one, there is an error in the log file when following code is run

```
ContactFilter filter = new ContactFilter(UserContext.Current);
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find endpoint element with name 'amNetTcp' and contract 'Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.

Previously, there was no need to configure core service in console config file, it was enough to place it on the CM server.

Any help?

Comment: Worth compare the **[Tridion-Home]\webservices\Web.config** and **[Tridion-Home]\webservices\AudienceManager\Web.config**  on both servers, may be one of the servers not installed AM or may be one of the servers installed with legacy?

Comment: There was installed certain hotfix on environment related to AM and probably something about binding for AM is changed. Solution was to ad binding, end point and core service behaviour configuration in config file of console application